# Name of variable and variable in function

Tags: r

I'm working with the following function

```
MeanMatch <- function(df1, df2){
  df2_means <- df2 %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_all(mean,na.rm=TRUE)
  TempJoined <- df1 %>% left_join(df2_means,by='cyl')
```

Now I have to specify the factor variable ('cyl' from `mpg` dataset in library ggplot2). What I want to do is let the user supply the factor variable as a function argument, just once. Like:

```
MeanMatch <- function(df1, df2, FactorVar){
  df2_means <- df2 %>% group_by(FactorVar) %>% summarise_all(mean,na.rm=TRUE)
  TempJoined <- df1 %>% left_join(df2_means,by='FactorVar')
```

and if they want to use cyl from mpg then they can just write `FactorVar=cyl` as argument. But of course the `by='FactorVar'` part of the function doesn't work. How can I do this?

I don't mind solutions where I input it as `MeanMatch(...,"cyl")` or `MeanMatch(...,cyl)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function :

```
library(dplyr)

MeanMatch <- function(df1, df2, FactorVar){
  df2_means <- df2 %>% group_by_at(FactorVar) %>% summarise_all(mean,na.rm=TRUE)
  TempJoined <- df1 %>% left_join(df2_means,by=FactorVar)
}
```

and call it as :

```
MeanMatch(df1, df2,"cyl")
```

Comment: ```group_by("cyl")``` won't work. Just try ```mpg %>% group_by("cyl") %>% summarise_all(mean,na.rm=TRUE)```